# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am getting above error. This is for the `App.js` file for the following code. How can I get rid of this error?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';

const Dashboard = () =>{ <h2> Dashboard </h2>};

const SurveyNew = () =>{ <h2> SurveyNew </h2>};

const Landing = () =>{<h2> Landing </h2>};

const App = () => {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Route exact path="/" component = {Landing} />
                    <Route exact path="/surveys" component= {Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="/surveys/new" component= {SurveyNew} /> 
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: show your render function for `App`, it's probably missing a `return` statement

Comment: Hi @FuzzyTree, thanks, I have updated the code for App, can you please suggest what could be the problem? I have already included return.

Comment: I would double check your import to make sure you are getting the right file, if all is right, check to make sure if you are using Git there is no disconnect between the current version of the App.js file and the one being compiled.

Comment: are you getting any errors? what happens if you render just a `div` with text in it istead of `App`? (make sure you include the `bundle.js` script etc..)

Comment: sorry guys, EricHasselbring and Sagivbg, I was also getting some warning in the console and it helped me solved that error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also getting the following warning for some of the silly code in my App.js

`[1]   Line 6:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

I have refactored that expression to assignment and it fixed my problem by removing the `{` from the expressions.